# How do I remove the extra pixels at the top of a ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, layout, scrollview, pixel

I have been working on an app that allows you to create a Truth Table and save it into HTML for use in word.  I have the app working fine but I am trying to clean it up a bit.  I have the following layout code to allow you to scroll the table while still keeping the name row at the top:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/nameTable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/nameRow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/TruthTableLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#000000" >
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This works fine for me overall, but when I scroll the table it doesn't fade immediately and instead shows a few pixels above the name row.  So my question is how can I make those pixels go away?

Because I don't have the reputation to post images, here is a link to a screenshot of what I'm talking about.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGQcf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters your margin here:

```
   <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/nameTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" >
```

should be 0 on the top.  SO if you need side margins it should be:

```
   <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/nameTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" >
```

Comment: Gah, I didn't even think of that!  I will be home soon to test it.

Comment: Got it tested, works great.  Can't believe I didn't see that, I have been stuck for days.  I would upvote but I don't have the rep to do so yet.